# Display entry post date

Tags: entry, datetime

How do I display my entry post date, formated as "May 24, 2015"?

I know this is a very basic question, but I can never find these easy answers in either the Craft or Twig documentation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
{{ entry.postDate | date("M d, Y") }}
```

Inside the date filter, you use the date formatting values documented in the [PHP date() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Also, see [Craft's DateTime documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/datetime), and the [Twig date() filter documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) for more information on the topic.

Comment: Probably also worth including this link: [entry.postDate](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#postDate)